# First-Order Logic: Simplifying $\exists x. (P(x))\,(\lambda y.see(y,x))$

Tags: first-order-logic, lambda-calculus

In [Chapter 10](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch10.html) section 4.2 (of the on-line documentation supporting the [Natural Language Toolkit](http://www.nltk.org/)), there are 3 sets of equations (39), (40), (41). The author talked about how careful one should be in selecting variables due to  $\beta$-reduction. My problem is I cannot see how $\beta$-reduction is taking place moving from equation (40a) to (41a). Here's the 3 equations:

**39a)** `\y.see(y, x)`

**40a)** `\P.exists x.P(x)(\y.see(y, x))`

**41a)** `exists x.see(x, x)`

So here's my interpretation:

The $\lambda$-calculus expression for **39a** is $$\lambda y.see(y,x)$$

The $\lambda$ term added to the term converting to **40a** is $\lambda P.(\exists x. (P(x)))$ and so it converts to **40a** which is

$$\lambda P.(\exists x. (P(x)))\,(\lambda y.see(y,x))$$

So since $x$ is the free variable in **40a**, how do I reduce it to yield **41a**? I'm thinking (first line is copied from above...which means there might already be mistakes in that line)

$$\lambda P.(\exists x. (P(x)))\,(\lambda y.see(y,x))$$
removing the $\lambda P$ term:
$$\exists x. (P(x))\,(\lambda y.see(y,x))$$
sub. all occurrences of $x$ on LHS with $(\lambda y.see(y,x))$ term:
$$\exists x. ((\lambda y.see(y,x))$$
and somehow yields

$$\exists x. see(x,x)$$

which is **41a**. Is there a mistake in how I do the $\beta$-reduction?

Comment: Please, provide a more informative title to your question.

Comment: $\beta$-reduction is "evaluating" the function. Here we have the function $\lambda P (\exists x P(x))$ and we replace $P$ with the fucntion (one-argument) $\lambda y (\text {see }(y,x))$. The result is $(\exists x \ \text {see }(x,x))$.

Comment: Consider a simpler example: the function $\lambda x (x+3)$ and evaluate it to $2$. What you get is $2+3$ which is a number and not more a function. The same with a "function of fucntion".

Comment: hey i'm still not very clear on how this works. So replacing $P$ do I get $\exists x. (\lambda y.see(y,x))$ ?

Comment: The issue is with replacing $P$ with $λy (\text {see}(y,x))$ that has a free var $x$. In this case, the $x$ is "captured" by the quantifier changing the meaning: $\exists x \ \text {see}(x,y)$ does not mean the same as $\exists x \ \text {see}(x,x)$.

Comment: is it something like "be a $P$ such that there exists an $x$ where $P$ is a function of $x$" and now it's something like "there exists an $x$ such that there is a $y$ such that $y$ sees $x$"?

Comment: @bryansis2010 Have you learned functional programming before? I think it will certainly help. (I am kind of on the opposite side of knowing FP but not $\lambda$-calculus.)

Comment: @AlexVong it is very unfortunate but this is the first time i'm encountering lambda-calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$β$ -reduction is the process of "evaluating" the function.

The $\lambda$ symbolism is aimed at avoiding the "sloppiness" of the traditional mathematical symbolism where (usually) $f(x)$ denotes the *function* and $f(a)$ denotes the value of the function for input $a$.

Thus, the function (of one argument) is denoted $\lambda x . f(x)$ and its value for input $a$ is the result of the "application" of $\lambda x . f(x)$ to argument $a$, getting:

> $\lambda x . f(x)(a)$ that reduces to the "usual" $f(a)$.

See the simple example of the function $\lambda x . \text {walk}(x)$ applied to argument $\text{angus}$ to get $\text {walk} (\text {angus})$.

So far, quite simple.

A little bit tricky is the next step: to consider a function whose argument is not an "individual" but a function, like:

> $λP . P(\text {angus})$.

In this case, we have a "function-of-$P$"; if we applies it to argument (a function) $λx . \text {walk}(x)$ what we get is:

> $λP . P(\text {angus})(λx . \text {walk}(x))$ i.e. $λx . \text {walk}(x)(\text {angus})$.

The final step is evaluating the resulting function of $x$ to the argument $\text {angus}$ getting $\text {walk}(\text {angus})$.

---

In the example with the quantifier inside, the difference is that $∃x P(x)$ is not a function of $x$.

When the variable $P$ is replaced with the name of a function, the result will be a sentence that does not refer to any $x$. Thus the $λ$ sign must disappear.

If we read the name of the function $λP . (\exists x \ P(x))$ as:

> "being a $P$ such that there is something that is a $P$",

we have to compare it to:

> (41.b) "there is something such that it sees $z$",

versus:

> (41.a) "there is something such that it sees itself".

---

The story is this (about predicate logic): in an expression $\forall x \ \alpha(x)$ (the same with $\exists x$) we cannot replace $x$ with a term containing $x$ free, because the "capturing" of the new occurrence of $x$ by the quantifier will change the meaning.

Silly example from arithmetic: from the soud $\exists x \ (x=0)$ we can get the wrong $\exists x \ (x+1=0)$ if we put $x+1$ in place of $x$.

Comment: yeah! this is so much clearer i think the textbook failed to communicate this whole answer and that's why i'm confused. i've gotten some light on the final part but should be able to sleep on it and get there.

Comment: just to be very sure $\lambda P .(\exists x P(x)) (\lambda y . see(y, x))$ evaluates to $\exists x (\lambda y . see(y, x)) (x) $ and finally by substituting $y$ with $x$ you get the result $\exists x. see(x, x)$ - there is something such that it sees itself.

Comment: @bryansis2010 - comments: but recalls that all the stuff is aimed at convincing you that this subst is wrong !

Comment: @bryansis2010 - second one: NOT exactly. Forget for the moment about see(y,x) and consider only walk(x). The meaning of $\exists x \ walk(x)$ is simply: "someone walks". With $λP.(∃xP(x))(λy.walk(y))$ what bwe get is the subst of the variable $P$ with the name of the function walk. Thus, the resul will be:  $∃x \ walk(x)$, because we have evaluated the fucntion $λP.(∃xP(x))$ to the argument $λx.walk(x)$.

Comment: yes and hence, given an expression $\lambda x . f(x)(a)$ NLTK first checks if the free variables in $a$ is a bound variable in any subterms of $f$, and if it does, it produces an alphabetic variant.

Comment: With see(y,x) we do not evaluate it to $x$: $x$ is simply part of the expression and it stay where it is...

Comment: sorry, wrong way of expressing it, but yes i understood your final explanation too